# How to find AP's current channel when beacon frame is seen on multiple channels like 4, 5, 6 while sniffing

Tags: wifi

I am trying to find an answer for the question in the title, but I couldn't find anything.

The question is: I have three sniffers which are capturing packets on different channels like channel 4, 5, and 6. On all three sniffers, I am getting beacon frames from the same AP for the same SSID. From this, how do I find the AP's current operating channel?

Is there any field in the beacon frame that indicates this?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark with beacon frame]

You can find the current channel number by looking at 'DS Parameter set'. In the picture, the AP's operating channel is 5.